# Is there a benefit to more villagers when Norende is complete?

Tags: bravely-default

In Bravery Default, one way you can restore Norende is by connecting online and getting villagers to help speed up build/upgrade/clearing times, at the same time you can also get new players to summon in battle (however this is limited to 20 unprotected players but your villager count will go up regardless).

After everything is done (every area unlocked, every building upgraded to max) is there any benefit to be getting more villages for Norende?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no direct benefit to more villagers once Norende is completely rebuilt. I have over 500 villagers, and it seems I still have the same amount of animated people running about as ever.

But do remember that each new StreetPass may bring a new Nemesis, which you can fight for Exp, JP and perhaps an item. Thus a side-benefit to more StreetPasses is more opportunities to fight Nemeses.

Answer (score 1):

Once the village is completely restored, there is no benefit to having more villagers other than watching more tiny people running around in panic when a nemesis appears.